# Why does CHARINDEX function return an index for 'Œ' in string 'manoeuvre'?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have this SQL code

```
declare @s varchar(8000) = 'manoeuvre'
select  CHARINDEX(char(140), @s, 0)
```

char(140) = Œ, which dose not exist in the string 'manoeuvre'.
yet SQL server returns the following

> 4 (indicating it had located the char(140) on this line)

if I replace 'Œ' with a '*' I get

> man*uvre

it seem like SQL has replaced the 'o' and 'e' with the one character, but why?
why is is replacing 'oe' with 'Œ'?

the same effect can be see with the string 'mass' and 'ß' (which I believe is German for double s). replacing on this character returns the sting 'ma*'.

Is SQL trying to do something "smart" under the covers?

EDIT
Extra information:

SQL server 2008 R2.

collation of database is Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Can you edit the question to include the version and the collation of the database where you're running this test, plus the locale of the user you're connecting with?

Comment: Under my default collation your query returns `0`

Comment: @ Ed Harper, I’m afraid I don’t understand what you mean by "the locale of the user you're connecting with", do you mean the Physical location?

@ Martin Smith: what's your database collation set to?

Comment: @ Martin Smith: What result do you get if you run the following?
select @s = N'mass'

select CHARINDEX(char(223), @s, 0)

Comment: There are a number of places in SQL Server documentation that refer to ["Code page Conversions"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx), without really explaining what that means. Anyone find a definitive reference?

Comment: @Minty - Treats `ss` and `ß` as equal. You might need to use a binary collation or a SQL collation to get the effect you want. e.g. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` appears to work

Comment: [See connect item here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/341130/-and-ss-are-not-equal) for some discussion on `ss` and `ß`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look up that sign (ASCII 140) it is described as

> capital OE ligature

See [www.table-ascii.com](http://www.table-ascii.com) for instance

try

```
select  CHARINDEX(char(140), @s COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, 0)
```

which will do a binary search.

Comment: This solves the problem for 'manoeuvre' and 'Œ', however the problem with 'mass' and 'ß', remains.
And unfortunately doesn’t answer the question "why is this happening?".
Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: try using `Latin1_General_BIN`.